# How to log each statement of a JUnit test method

Tags: java, junit

By default the jUnit report only logs at test case level: 'pass' or 'fail'otherwise plus the stacktrace.

What I would need is to log a level deeper, each line of code from the JUnit @Test method. So the report has a general info (test pass or fail) and a detailed info with each step executed and eventually the one that failed.

Below current code structure:

```
public abstract class TestClass{
    static Logger logger = log4j.Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class); 

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception{
            driver.findElement(By.id("some_id")).click();
            Assert.assertEquals("product edit", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: You already know which one failed, as it's in the standard JUnit output.  And you also know what happened before, because it's in your test code.  If your test-cases are so complex that you feel you need line-by-line logging, you should probably consider refactoring your tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because the source code is no more visible after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only manually with a log instruction before/after each line in you test method, for example:

```
public abstract class TestClass{
    static Logger logger = log4j.Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class); 

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception{
            logger.info("Calling click method on some id...");
            driver.findElement(By.id("some_id")).click();
            logger.info("Testing driver's title");
            Assert.assertEquals("product edit", driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```